# Make Faces of Icosphere Periodically fall with Rotation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am trying to find a way to make half an icosphere slowly fall apart without having to animate all the faces manually as individual objects. Physics doesn't matter but they should rotate as they fall. I imagine this is possible with geometry nodes somehow but I can't figure it out. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, i really liked the challenge and needed several hours ;) here is a working node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Heroic :) Now the challenge is to crunch it down to 6 nodes XD

Comment: Thank you! That you write that - means a lot to me! It still looks like it is far from being perfect...and yes...you can use less nodes, i am sure. I was just happy that it worked...... kind of... ;)